# How to fix code 215: Bad Authentication data on Twitter Oauth (Direct Messages)?

Tags: java, api, twitter, message, twitter-oauth

**UPDATE 2**

SOLVED, I was missing Header String tutorial instructions at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request.html

**Answer to my question:** Headers must not contain any json data.

Here's my fully functional project, just insert your credentials and you are ready to send Twitter direct messages:
https://github.com/ricarrrdo/gs-rest-service

**Note:** I'm using Spring deprecated AsyncRestTemplate, so if someone knows how to use the new WebClient, please upgrade restASyncClientBody() method inside Application.java - it would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE 1**

https://github.com/ricarrrdo/gs-rest-service/blob/master/src/main/java/hello/Application.java#L2-L12

This link above is my spring boot project which recreates Twitter given example at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html to authenticate and authorize a API request. 
It's working fine, just compile/run with `mvn spring-boot:run` and watch console output.
You can `check lines 41-52`, which are the same parameters used in Twitter example.

**Problem/Question**

I'm trying to send a Direct Message on Twitter via Twitter API but I keep getting `Bad Authentication data` error. How should I change my code to be able to send direct messages?

I mean: In https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html there's an example with how to create a valid Oauth header using x-www-form-urlencoded parameters. **But how can I create valid Oauth headers when sending Json?**

Twitter tutorial for direct messages here - 
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/new-event

**Notes**

Authorization header needed to send a direct message:

> authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY",
>   oauth_nonce="AUTO_GENERATED_NONCE",
>   oauth_signature="AUTO_GENERATED_SIGNATURE",
>   oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
>   oauth_timestamp="AUTO_GENERATED_TIMESTAMP",
>   oauth_token="USERS_ACCESS_TOKEN", oauth_version="1.0"

Comment: Can you please explain more? what do you mean by Answer to my question: Headers must not contain any json data? The header you provided is not a json format.